# How to pass variables and functions to components in react?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to create a component and call each instance with individual values. Each component (<NewRanger .../>) should also use a different handleChangeFunction. I pass this as follows: handleChangeFunction={handleChangeEm100} where handleChangeEm100 is the individual name of the function. This should then be taken over within the component as onChange={{handleChangeFunction}}. But somehow it crashes for me without any concrete error. Am I doing something conceptually wrong here?

```
function Check() {

const [valueEm100, setValueEm100] = React.useState([96, 99]);

const handleChangeEm100 = (event, newValue, activeThumb) => {
        ..
};

function NewRanger({valueName, valueRange, valueNameRange, handleChangeFunction,
        steps, minV, maxV}) {

        return (
        <>
        <div className='Text-EM-main'>
        <div className="Text-EM-0">  
        {valueName}:
        </div>

        <div className="Text-EM-1">
        {{valueRange}[0]}
        </div>

        <div className="Text-EM-2">  
            <Slider
            getAriaLabel={() => valueNameRange}
            value={{valueRange}}
            onChange={{handleChangeFunction}}
            valueLabelDisplay="auto"
            getAriaValueText={valuetext}
            disableSwap
            step={{steps}}
            marks
            min={{minV}}
            max={{maxV}}
            />
        </div>

        <div className="Text-EM-3">   
        {{valueRange}[1]}
        </div>
        </div>
        </>
        )

      }

    return (
    <>
    <NewRanger 
    valueName={"EM100"}
    valueRange={valueEm100} 
    valueNameRange={'em100 range'} 
    handleChangeFunction={handleChangeEm100} 
    steps={1} minV={90} maxV={110}/>
    </>
    )
```

Comment: *"How to pass variables and functions to components in react?"* - As props, exactly the way your code already does it.  *"But somehow it crashes for me without any concrete error."* - How specifically is it failing?  "Somehow it crashes" doesn't really tell us anything.  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all never define you components in other components. Move NewRanger to outside of the Check component. Also you are using extra {} in your code. Here is the updated code:

```js
function NewRanger({valueName, valueRange, valueNameRange, handleChangeFunction,
        steps, minV, maxV}) {

        return (
        <>
        <div className='Text-EM-main'>
        <div className="Text-EM-0">  
        {valueName}:
        </div>

        <div className="Text-EM-1">
        {valueRange[0]}
        </div>

        <div className="Text-EM-2">  
            <Slider
            getAriaLabel={() => valueNameRange}
            value={valueRange}
            onChange={handleChangeFunction}
            valueLabelDisplay="auto"
            getAriaValueText={valuetext}
            disableSwap
            step={steps}
            marks
            min={minV}
            max={maxV}
            />
        </div>

        <div className="Text-EM-3">   
        {valueRange[1]}
        </div>
        </div>
        </>
        )

      }

function Check() {

const [valueEm100, setValueEm100] = React.useState([96, 99]);

const handleChangeEm100 = (event, newValue, activeThumb) => {
        ..
};

    return (
    <>
    <NewRanger 
    valueName={"EM100"}
    valueRange={valueEm100} 
    valueNameRange={'em100 range'} 
    handleChangeFunction={handleChangeEm100} 
    steps={1} minV={90} maxV={110}/>
    </>
    )
```